# Possibility to change code in python without using "power" and "factorial" function to calculate the value of cos (x) with a Taylor Series

Tags: python, math, factorial

I am trying to calculate the value of `cos(x)` with a Taylor Series:
[Value of cos(x) with Taylor Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFLfP.png)

My code looks like this.

```
x = float(input("x: "))
n = int(input("n: "))

k=0
s=0
sign=1

while k<n:
    term = sign * x **(k)/math.factorial(k)
    s = s+term
    k = k+2
    sign = -sign
```

Is there a way to not use the `**`-power or the `factorial` function and no other function. My idea is to run the code just with one loop.

`n` is representing the `n`-th element in the series like `x^4/x!` is the 3rd Element of the Taylor Series.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the language's inbuilt features? While you're at it, why not decide you don't want to use `*` to multiply and you'd rather do it by loopy addition? If this is a homework exercise (and it smells like one because why else would you voluntarily tie both hands behind your back?) you need to make an attempt yourself and then ask a specific question about your attempt instead of just "how can I do this?"

Comment: @PranavHosangadi There's really no need for the hectoring tone. My advice to you is to think about how to constructively engage a person who has less experience with this stuff than you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that 4! = 2! * 3 * 4; notice that x ^ 4 = x ^ 2 * x * x.

Instead of calculating these each time, you might be able to do something like this:

```py
x = float(input("x: "))
n = int(input("n: "))

k = 0
s = 0
sign = 1

factorial = 1
x_k = 1

while k < n:
    term = sign * x_k / factorial
    s = s + term
    k = k + 2

    # calculate next k! and x ^ k
    factorial *= k * (k - 1)
    x_k *= x * x
    sign = -sign
```

Comment: I tried the code for x=3 und n=3 and don't get the same results. Which code is wrong?

Comment: It looks like I accidentally started at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @tabularaza does that look okay now? Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Now I get the same results! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @tabularaza Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm glad you got the help you needed, but please [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are satisfied, so people will know that the question has been answered.